# Connecting Python Calculations To HTML

Tags: python, html

I want to be able to display calculations done in python code on an HTML page I created. I know this is a common thing, but I don't know how to do that properly. For example, if I wanted to click a submit button on a webpage to do some kind of complicated operation on the back end and then display it on that same page.

Comment: which web framework you are using?

Comment: I'm using django. I'm assuming that's a good solution? I'm only now starting to learn it

Comment: first you should learn django

Comment: Thank you, yes I actually went through it yesterday. Can PHP do the same thing? Or am I better off just learning django?

Comment: yes you can do the same thing using PHP. but in my view point if you are doing your calculations using python so it is better to use Django. `Note:`every programming language have some pros and cons you cannot say that this is programming language or framework is good and this one is bad.

Comment: Gotcha, thank you for the help. Much appreciated

Comment: Glad to help you